# Join measurements to fieldkeys in InfluxDB using map and reduce functions

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

In InfluxDB 2.x, I need to create a simplified data dictionary listing all of the measurements and their fields. I want to get all of the `fieldKeys` for all of the `measurements` within a bucket. The query should get all of the measurements for the bucket, then for each `measurement` get all of the `fieldKeys` and concat them into a large string separated with commas. The end result should have two columns with the `measurement` and list of `fieldKeys` like the following:

```
mem,"field1,field2,field3"
cpu,"field1,field2,field3,field4"
```

I can create the concatenated list of `fieldKeys` with the following function:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"
import "strings"
import "array"

getFieldsForMeasure = (measureName) => schema.measurementFieldKeys(bucket: "mybucket", measurement: measureName)
    |> reduce(
        fn: (r, accumulator) => ({sum: r._value + "," + accumulator.sum}),
        identity: {sum: ""},
    )

getFieldsForMeasure(measureName: "mem")
```

Putting that with a map function and a query for the measruements look like the following:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"
import "strings"
import "array"

getFieldsForMeasure = (measureName) => schema.measurementFieldKeys(bucket: "mybucket", measurement: measureName)
    |> reduce(
        fn: (r, accumulator) => ({sum: r._value + "," + accumulator.sum}),
        identity: {sum: ""},
    )

data = schema.measurements(bucket: "mybucket")
    |> yield()
    |> findColumn(
        fn: (key) => key._field == "",
        column: "_value",
    )

data |> map(fn: (r) => ({fieldsList:  string(v:   getFieldsForMeasure(measureName: r._value))}))
```

Although, I get this error:

```
Error: failed to execute query: 400 Bad Request: error @20:1-20:5: expected stream[{A with _value: B}] but found [{A with _value: B}] (array) (argument tables)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because [findColumn](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/findcolumn/) returns an array, but pipeline functions require stream input. It seems that you have just misplaced it in the code, I guess you meant to use it for fields list extraction in `getFieldsForMeasure`.

So I hope the following returns expected result:

```js
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"
import "strings"
import "array"

getFieldsForMeasure = (measureName) => schema.measurementFieldKeys(bucket: "mybucket", measurement: measureName)
    |> reduce(
        fn: (r, accumulator) => ({sum: r._value + "," + accumulator.sum}),
        identity: {sum: ""},
    )
    |> findColumn(column: "sum", fn: (key) => true)


data = schema.measurements(bucket: "mybucket")

data 
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with fieldsList: string(v: getFieldsForMeasure(measureName: r._value)[0])}))
```

Output:

```
win_cpu  Percent_User_Time,Percent_Processor_Time,Percent_Privileged_Time,Percent_Interrupt_Time,Percent_Idle_Time,Percent_DPC_Time,
win_disk Percent_Idle_Time,Percent_Free_Space,Percent_Disk_Write_Time,Percent_Disk_Time,Percent_Disk_Read_Time,Free_Megabytes,Current_Disk_Queue_Length,
win_mem ...
```